# Таймер обратного отсчета на чистом js.

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Таймер обратного отсчета на чистом js, работает во всех браузерах кроме IE. Подскажите пожалуйста.

```
 let clocksHeader = () => {
 let minutes = document.body.querySelector(".header-minutes");
 let seconds = document.body.querySelector(".header-seconds");    
 let minutes_data = 44;
 let seconds_data = 59;

 let timer = setInterval(function() {
     minutes.innerHTML = minutes_data;
     seconds.innerHTML = seconds_data-- ;

     if(seconds_data < 10) { 
         seconds.innerHTML = '<span>0</span>' + seconds_data;
     }
     if(minutes_data < 10) {
         minutes.innerHTML = '<span>0</span>' + minutes_data;
     }
     if(seconds_data == 0) {
         seconds_data = 59;
         minutes_data--;
         if(minutes_data < 0) clearInterval(timer)
     }
 }, 1000);  

 }
 clocksHeader();
```

Comment: Про полифилы в курсе что такое?

Comment: Уже знаю... 
Спасибо!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

В IE нет поддержки стрелочных функций.